# iOS-Charts: Set UIImageViews in accordance with PieChart's Pie positions?

Tags: ios, swift, pie-chart, ios-charts

I'm currently using iOS-Charts (https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) in order to present a pie chart. I got it working, and can highlight it and whatnot. But I need to place icons next to these pies that are presented. So I'd like to place an `UIImageView` outside the pie chart, but in the "middle" of each corresponding pie. Check the image for clarification. Is there a simple way to do this? This also needs to be dynamic, of course, so I can't just place them in the storyboard.

I can get how much of a circle each pie consists of, in degrees or percentage, but I don't know how to use this in order to get positions to place the `UIImageView`. Any suggestions?

Edit: Forgot the image duh [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let FDEG2RAD = CGFloat(M_PI / 180.0)
var drawAngles = chart.drawAngles
var absoluteAngles = chart.absoluteAngles
var animator = chart.animator
var center = chart.centerCircleBox
var r: CGFloat = YOUR_DRAWING_RADIUS_HERE

for (var i = 0; i < absoluteAngles.count; i++)
{
  var offset =  drawAngles[i] / 2.0
  var x = (r * cos(((rotationAngle + absoluteAngles[i] - offset) * animator.phaseY) * FDEG2RAD) + center.x)
  var y = (r * sin(((rotationAngle + absoluteAngles[i] - offset) * animator.phaseY) * FDEG2RAD) + center.y)

  // Put whatever you want now on the x/y
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this code, but it looks I'll take your word for it since you are the developer of the ios-charts. I made my own solution 20 minutes ago which works fine, but is not at all connected to the ios-charts. I just get the centerPoint of my ChartPieView and calculate a point depending on the width, height, and the angle amount which each pie occupies in the PieChart. So I simply use Pythagoras theorem and use the angle provided by PieChartView.drawAngles.

This looks a lot cleaner though, thank you!

Comment: @ClockWise I've updated it a bit, as you really do not need to recalculate the angles - but still need to do the cos/sin to take the x/y

Comment: @ClockWise, how did you get the centerPoint of the ChartPieView? Neither pieChart.centerCircleBox, nor regular old pieChart.center is marking the true center of the pie chart.

Comment: but this isn't working when pie chart is scrolling ... this images should scroll with the slices. how can I achieve this ?

Comment: updated Question and answer with new version of iso-chart ( v 3.0 ) is here -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/42113512/2739657