# add an image for each slice in iOS-chart pieChart

Tags: ios, swift, pie-chart, ios-charts

I'm using [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). I want to create a pie chart like below image. I have done all the confings, but I have problem with adding the image in the circle beside the values outside the circle.

[image]

Can anybody help me how to to add the circles and image inside it ?

**UPDATED**:
note that the pie chart will scroll and those images should scroll with the related slices.

**UPDATED**:
I used @Aditya Garg sample code to draw images beside the position of labels, and my chart is now looks like this :

[image]

I set the imageViewFrame like this:

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPos-10, y: yPos+10, width: 20, height: 20)
```

**UPDATED**:
[Github Pull request for ios-chart repo swift](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/pull/3207)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the circle and the image inside is easy. First create a UIImageView, change the corner radius, and put the image inside

```
//Assuming you have declared a UIImageView and an image
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.image = image
```

You can create as many of these as you need programmatically

```
func drawCircle(xPos:CGFloat, yPos:CGFloat, name: String){ 
    let image = UIImage(named: name)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPos-10, y: yPos+10, width: (image?.size.width)!, height: (image?.size.height)!)
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.tag = 1000 //this is so we can later remove and redraw the circle in a new position
    pieChart.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

The trickier part is drawing these images at the correct place (the circle image is always aligned with the middle of the pie chart section). You have to calculate the angle between these sections manually, and then add in the UImageView we created to this position

These are the geometric properties that pieChart exposes to us

```
let FDEG2RAD = CGFloat(M_PI / 180.0)
var absoluteAngles : [CGFloat] = pieChart.absoluteAngles
absoluteAngles.insert(0, at: 0)
var center = pieChart.centerCircleBox
center.x = center.x - 15 //correction factor for center, adjust these as you see fit
center.y = center.y - 11
let r: CGFloat = pieChart.radius + 30 //distance from center
```

Where absolute angles is an array of the slice angles. These always get bigger and end at 360 degrees. Note that we manually insert 0 at the beginning so that the code works nicely.

There is a bug where centerCircleBox does not return the true center. To fix this use this function to draw an image on where the pieChart *says* its center is and then adjust the correction factor to get it in the true center. (make sure to add a smallish image file to your project, i used a red x mark)

```
   func drawCenterX(xPos:CGFloat, yPos:CGFloat){
   let xred = "xmarks.png"
   let image = UIImage(named: xred)
   let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
   imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: (image?.size.width)!, height: (image?.size.height)!)
   pieChart.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

For the math, we simply have to keep track of our last absolute angle, our current absolute angle and find the angle in between. Add this onto our last value to find the true angle and then convert to X,Y coordinates. Note that the larger the Y gets, the more down the screen it goes, so we have to subtract not add.

```
let x = center.x + (r * sin((absoluteAngles[last] + ((absoluteAngles[current] - absoluteAngles[last] )/2)) * FDEG2RAD))
let y = center.y - (r * cos((absoluteAngles[last] + ((absoluteAngles[current] - absoluteAngles[last] )/2)) * FDEG2RAD))
```

Now, just iterate through the absoluteAngles array, calculate the position, and place the UIImageView here. See the full code below

```
func setLabels(vals : [Int]){

    let subViews = self.pieChart.subviews //this removes the previous UIImageViews
    for subview in subViews{
        if subview.tag == 1000 {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    let FDEG2RAD = CGFloat(M_PI / 180.0)
    var absoluteAngles : [CGFloat] = pieChart.absoluteAngles
    absoluteAngles.insert(0, at: 0)
    var center = pieChart.centerCircleBox
    center.x = center.x - 15 //correction factor for center, adjust these as you see fit
    center.y = center.y - 11
    let r: CGFloat = pieChart.radius + 30 //distance from center
    var current = 1
    var last = 0

    for value in vals{


        let x = center.x + (r * sin((absoluteAngles[last] + ((absoluteAngles[current] - absoluteAngles[last] )/2)) * FDEG2RAD))
        let y = center.y - (r * cos((absoluteAngles[last] + ((absoluteAngles[current] - absoluteAngles[last] )/2)) * FDEG2RAD)) 

        last = current
        current = current + 1

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { //Adds a nice animation that brings the circle in from off screen
            //Implement your own logic for how you want to pass in the name of the section to the function we defined above.
            self.drawCircle(xPos: x, yPos: y, name: name)
            }, completion: nil)
    }
    drawCenterX(xPos: center.x, yPos: center.y)//visually locate center
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: everything makes sense but when should I call the setLabels function ? consider that the pie chart is scrolling and those images should scroll with the circle slices.. So should I override any function ?

Comment: Do you have a setChart function anywhere? In my project the pie chart is continuously being updated so I call the function above whenever I redraw the chart.

Comment: I have the setChart function but I will call it once in viewDidLoad, where can I call it to update continuously the frames?

Comment: Hmm, I see what you're asking now. Animating the labels should be a separate question. Accept mine as the solution, and post another one. The quick explanation would be that inside the animation section above, you would animate it from a start position (top of the pie chart) to the desired position along an arc that you have to define.

Comment: okay, forget the animation, how you would arrange the positions of images not to overlay the labels and other images? I will upload you the image now with my data to see what it is looks like.

Comment: I think that I have to move the values and place the image position instead of the values positions. but I tried and couldn't find anything to move the values positions. can you suggest anything ? @Aditya Garg

Comment: Okay, the problem is that pieChart has a bug where the .centerCircleBox method does not return the true center of the chart. You have three options of attack. Ive added a debug method that will draw an image at the supposed center. You can fix the correction factors to find the true center. You can also change the distance r from 30 to something higher to avoid overlap between image and numbers. Lastly there is +10/-10 correction factor you can change in the drawCircle function. Cheers

Comment: I got close but I couldn't reach to exact number that would show me what I want , I think this is not working in this form, there has to be another way to get the positions ...